# Angular2 Templating: Safe Navigation Operator and *ngIf

Tags: templates, angular, asynchronous, angular2-template

My goal is to hide an element when no items are available. My template so far:

```ts
<div *ngIf="(projects | async)?.userProjects.length !== 0">
    <div class="sortWrapper">
        <h3>Your projects</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="listElementWrapper">
        <div class="listElement" *ngFor="let userProject of (projects| async)?.userProjects" (click)="redirectToProject(project)">
            <h4>{{ userProject.ProjectName }}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The *ngFor with the safe navigation operator works as expected. The first line (*ngIf) doesn't though. As the `userProjects` property is async, the length somehow doesn't update. Did I miss a key concept here?

Component: `private projects: Observable<any[]>;`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nope.

Comment: What events does `projects` emit? Have you tried to subscribe to `projects` in code and console.log the events?

Comment: What do you mean by "what events"? The binding with the *ngFor works (which uses the same properties), so I think there's nothing wrong in the template.

Comment: Only reason it is not working is that the observable is returning an iterable which does not have a length property. Can you verify that a normal array is returned?

Comment: @PierreDuc I see, that makes sense. What's the right approach to do this?

Comment: Put your userProjects inside an array :). What kind of type is `userProjects`?

Comment: @PierreDuc God, I'm so confused because of all that observable stuff... userProjects is an array of Projects (custom type).

Comment: it does not really comply with your `projects` declaration: `private projects: Observable<any[]>;`. This means the observable itself returns an array. But your template says the observable returns an object with a property `userProjects` which on itself is an array. So which one is it :)?

Comment: Ok I see. It's an observable, now I typed it "Observable<any>" - what do I have to change now?

Comment: Nothing :( if you are sure `userProjects` is an array, and you did put `!== 0`, then i see no reasons why it shouldn't work, without an error. Can you perhaps create a plunkr to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Well if userProjects is an array of type Projects, maybe just assign it like so: `userProjects: Projects[];` and then the rest of your code should work, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `?` before `length` as well

```ts
<div *ngIf="(projects | async)?.userProjects?.length == 0">
```

Comment: Good idea, the "helper"-divs don't show up though?!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I believe you would like it to be `!== 0`. Then it will actually show when it has results :)</strike>

```
<div *ngIf="(projects | async)?.userProjects.length !== 0">
```

Apparently this is an issue in angular. Check here for more information:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9641

The solution could be to not use the async pipe and set a variable `userProjects` inside your component:

> untested code ahead

```
<div *ngIf="userProjects.length > 0">
    <div class="sortWrapper">
        <h3>Your projects</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="listElementWrapper">
        <div class="listElement" *ngFor="let userProject of userProjects" (click)="redirectToProject(project)">
            <h4>{{ userProject.ProjectName }}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the component something like this:

```
export class UserProjectsComponent {

   public userProjects: UserProject[] = [];

   public projectSub: Subscription;

   constructor(public projectService: ProjectService){}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.projectSub = this.projectService.getUserProjects().subscribe((userProjects) => {
          this.userProjects = userProjects
      });
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
      this.projectSub.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

You can however also define the userProjects on your projectService:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

  public get userProjects(): UserProject[] {
     return this._userProjects;
  }  

  private _userProjects: UserProject[] = [];

  constructor(private http: Http){}

  public getUserProjects(): void {
     this.http.get().map(resp => resp.json()).subscribe((userProjects) => {
          this._userProjects = userProjects;
     });
  }
}
```

and then you can keep the template as I defined above here, but change your component to the simpler:

```
export class UserProjectsComponent {

   public get userProjects(): UserProject[] {
      return this.projectService.userProjects;
   }

   constructor(public projectService: ProjectService){}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.projectService.getUserProjects();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's right, actually I posted it wrong because I tried with [hidden] too (which is reversed of course).

Comment: Ahh, i understand :) sometimes such mistakes can be easily overlooked

Comment: Somehow the build was (silently) corrupted - webpack did something strange to the polyfills. Thanks for the answer - good example.

Comment: @Sandrooco does that mean you no longer have the same issue?